# Rod and Tackle Combination for Beginner Fisher

Tags: fishing, fishing-tackle

I want to get into fishing but don't know the technical side because I just fish with rods pre-setup. So I decided that I wanted to get a spinning reel and am pretty sure I want a [Shakespeare ugly stick](http://www.uglystik.com/).

I want a general rod I can use to land anything from bream to a small catfish. What would the best combination of action, test #, reel, weight of end tackle be for a general fishing rod? I will be fishing mainly in bays/rivers/ponds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your choice of an ugly stick is fantastic. I fish more specialized rods now, but I have owned many ugly sticks over the years, and they are rock solid performers.

For the "small-water" fishing destinations and the species you say you'll be targeting, I would go for something in the 5-7' range - in a light rod power (to use Shakespeare parlance). Moderate to moderate fast action.

As you are a novice, I'd recommend using a heavier line weight than you might use after you have more experience - 10-12 lb test braided line. It has the diameter of something like a 4-6 lb monofilament, but greater strength, sensitivity, and performance overall. Look for a spinning reel that will hold 120 yards or so of 6 lb monofilament and it will hold much more briaded line. I believe Shakespeare offers combos that would probably be perfect. **Just make sure that whatever you buy is rated for saltwater**

The heavier line will definitely limit how far you can cast very light (<1/4 oz.) lures and rigs, but I think you'll lose fewer fish than if you were using 6lb test line.

With a rig like this you could fish for bluegills or crappie one day, and then fight nice sized stripers the next. And catfish should be no problem.

Comment: What about this one: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product//B00F0KMLCK/ref=twister_dp_update?ie=UTF8&psc=1 for example. I am thinking about getting the gx2, does that sound good? For line could you suggest a specific company that is trust worthy? Basically, I am shooting for a rod, reel, line and sufficient tackle for under 100 bucks. 
Does that sound possible? Tackle would just be extra hooks, swivels, floats and sinkers and maybe a couple lures.

Comment: Wrong link above...won't let me edit!! I meant this one:http://www.uglystik.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-PureFishing-Site/default/Product-Variation?pid=1314552&dwvar_1314552_MFRPN=USSP661MH%2f40CBO

Comment: @NULL - Those look like good setups. I like the MODEL # USSP502L/25CBO as it is light action. Heavier than that and it'll feel like you are using a broomstick on small fish. I use PowerPro braided line and have for years, but I have friends who use Spiderwire and other brands. I find that they're all pretty good nowadays. As far as lures go - start with a variety of bucktail jigs in sizes from 1/8 - 1oz. in white or white/chartreuse and you'll be on your way.